# Python: insert value to matrix

Tags: python, matrix, insertion

I have a Problem with the simple insertion into a matrix in python: (I am not very python experienced)

`matrix = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(10), len(10)), dtype=int)`

Now I want to insert specific values to the matrix index, e.g. at line 1, column 1.

How do i do that? I already was on https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy but with the insert-method it does not work.

I just want a simple style like: matrix[1][1] = 17

It has to be a matrix in that style, because after insertion I have to do a singular value decomposition.

Comment: `len(10)` throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: I think what you want is `matrix = numpy.zeros(shape=(10, 10), dtype=int)` No need to do len(), this returns the length of some objects, like lists.

Comment: oh yes thx... originally it was `matrix = numpy.zeros(shape=(len(myList), len(myOtherList)), dtype=int)`

Comment: What's wrong with `matrix[1][1] = 17`? But note that Python is zero indexed to the first line and column will be matrix[0][0]

Answer (score 3):

You're syntax is incorrect in the np.zeros constructor.

Here's what it should look like:

```
matrix = numpy.zeros(shape=(10, 10), dtype=int)
```

You can then set a value using normal array syntax:

```
matrix[1,4] = 10
print matrix

[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
```

P.S. as others have mentioned, Python references it's indexes from zero, not one. So to set row 4, column 5 the array indices would be matrix[3,4].

Comment: I cannot believe that... that works... I have already tried exactly that several times and the compiler always shows me an error like "there is no function assignment" or something like that. I am really confused about that... but now it works... Thx for you all! :-)